# is it feasible to call Angular UI page from wordpress website, using subdomain?

Tags: angular, wordpress, api

I have a static website on WordPress and there are 2 to 3 pages which has dynamic content and which does requires user authentication. 
So can I build these pages on angular side and call these pages from word-press's static website using subdomains ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the authentication works wor WordPress. But I'm sure you can make a link in your WordPress page to open an Angular app. The only problem is to add security to your Angular app.

Comment: it's an website only not an app. Just it is in angular. And yeah I have to figure out security part as well. Need to maintain sessions across multiple sub domains.